# Combine multiple d3.js datasets into a single data object

Tags: javascript, d3.js, underscore.js

I'm building an app that will allow the user to specify a few out of many possible `datasets` to compare.  Since each variable has millions of observations (which I will already have to truncate), I only want the browser to load the data that the user requests, rather than loading everything and only displaying what the user asks for.

I have not been able to find a simple method to merge d3 data objects into one bigger object.  Here is what I made to combine three fixed single column "`csv`" files:

```
<script src="d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="queue.v1.js"></script>
<script src="underscore.v1.js"></script>
<script>

   queue().defer(d3.csv, "hdata1.txt") //one column text file with header and data
      .defer(d3.csv, "hdata2.txt") //as above, but with a different header and data
      .defer(d3.csv, "hdata3.txt") //yet another single column file
      .awaitAll(function(error, results){ 
         console.log("input data", results);  //input data [Array[5], Array[5], Array[5]]
         var data=d3.transpose(results).map(function(x){ return _.extend(x[0], x[1], x[2])} );
         console.log("output data", data), //output data [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
         some_func(data); 
      });

   function some_func(data){
      //do stuff with the data
   };
</script>
```

This works, but it seems like overkill to need `d3.transpose`, `d3.map`, and `_.extend` to combine the objects sensibly.  Is there a more elegant way to merge several d3 data objects?

Comment: In short, no. D3 doesn't really provide functions to merge different data sets explicitly.